# Error when showing the value of VBDKR-WAERK in Form Painter ABAP

Tags: sapscript

I am trying to fix a bug in the Form Painter which is related to the VBDKR-WAERK. The problem is as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

So in place of VBDKR-WAERK should be EUR. The code in Form painter for this part is:

```
&VBDKR-ZTERM_TX1(IC)&
&'(='SKONTOWERT1(ICZ)' VBDKR-WAERK&)'&
&VBDKR-ZTERM_TX2(IC)&
&'(='SKONTOWERT2(ICZ)' VBDKR-WAERK&)'&
&VBDKR-ZTERM_TX3(IC)&
```

SKONTOWERT1 and SKONTOWERT2 are type KOMVD-KWERT.

May anyone know what the problem may be?
Please do tell me if you need additional information.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Leading & is missing? VBDKR-WAERK& => &VBDKR-WAERK&

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai yep that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field names in SAPScript always have to be entered with leading and closing '&':

VBDKR-WAERK& => &VBDKR-WAERK&

```
&VBDKR-ZTERM_TX1(IC)&
&'(='SKONTOWERT1(ICZ)' &VBDKR-WAERK&)'&
&VBDKR-ZTERM_TX2(IC)&
&'(='SKONTOWERT2(ICZ)' &VBDKR-WAERK&)'&
&VBDKR-ZTERM_TX3(IC)&
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is not about Smart Forms, I just saw that SAPScript and Smart Forms interpret differently the notation `&'pre-text'symbol'post-text'&`. SAPScript accepts symbols in `pre-text` and `post-text`, but Smart Forms doesn't (with `&'(='SKONTOWERT1(ICZ)' &VBDKR-WAERK&)'&`, I get the exception `FORMATTING_ERROR`, message ID `SSFCOMPOSER`, message number `308`, message "`Fields within fields are not allowed (SKONTOWERT1).`").

This notation works in both technologies:

```
(=&SKONTOWERT1(ICZ)& &VBDKR-WAERK&)
```

meaning

- Text "`(=`"
- followed by variable/symbol `SKONTOWERT1` (with `ICZ` being 3 individual characters each meaning respectively initial value (zero) not output, compress spaces, omit leading zeroes)
- followed by one space
- followed by variable/symbol `VBDKR-WAERK`
- followed by text "`)`"